# How to set Role when I am creating new User?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I've got simple application in Spring and I want to implement method which set role when i am creating new user. So Its my code. How should I give Set roles to last method?

Role.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NaturalId
    private RoleName name;

    public Role(){}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public RoleName getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(RoleName name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

RoleName enum

```
    public enum RoleName {
    ROLE_USER,
    ROLE_ADMIN
}
```

Setter method in User.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

And how should I fill this method?

```
  public User addUser(User user) {
    Role userRole = roleRepository.findRoleByName(RoleName.ROLE_USER);
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    newUser.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    newUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
    newUser.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
    newUser.setLastName(user.getLastName());
    newUser.setRoles();
    return userRepository.save(newUser);
}
```

I don't know what should i put in `newUser.setRoles()`

Comment: The parameter for the `setRoles` method should probably be a `Set<Role>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Stream of java 8 as bellow:

```
Set<Role> roles = Stream.of(userRole)
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

newUser.setRoles(roles);
```

Comment: I think userRole should be retrieved from roleRepository, else it will recreate new role in the role repository with the same name but different ID.

Comment: he already do it that: 
Role userRole = roleRepository.findRoleByName(RoleName.ROLE_USER);

Comment: My bad, then he should wrap the single role to a set.